# Can't upload file using PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I try a simple php upload file on Ubuntu, it not work. Even it work on Window

Here my html coded.

```
<form action="upload.php" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Here my php coded.

```
<?php
  $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

  if(move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$name)){
   echo "Your file was uploaded";
}
 else
{ 
 echo "Your file cound't upload";
}

?>
```

Comment: Most probably the issue is with file size. I am assuming you are uploading large file. Is that correct?

Comment: Check the permissions to the upload folder is that having write permission

Comment: Thank  Arun Kumar! My problem caused by permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change permission to UPLOAD file into upload folder on UBUNTU

Read + Write

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw upload/
```

Read + Write + Execute

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx upload/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have given the write access to the "APACHE" on the directory.

Hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by giving the write permission to the directory in ubuntu..

You can see here on how to give write permissions..

https://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to install php-xml extension.

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Worked perfectly after installing this extension.

The error I was getting

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "DOMDocument" not found in
> ../wp-content/plugins/svg-support/vendor/enshrined/svg-sanitize/src/Sanitizer.php:96
> .... ../wp-content/plugins/svg-support/functions/attachment.php(246):
> bodhi_svgs_sanitize()\